# Use numeric inside SQL statement in procedure

Tags: sql-server

How to use numeric variable in sql statement inside procedure?
This is my try:

```
create procedure ##sp_check (

    @tolerance numeric
)

AS

Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = '
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a
WHERE
    value > @tolerance
'
    exec sp_executesql @SQL

go

exec ##sp_check 1
```

and the ERROR: `Must declare the scalar variable "@tolerance".`
I think this is because the variable is invisible between `'` and `'` 
so I can do it by declaring `@tolerance` as varchar and in sql statement converting it into numeric but its a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly pass the variable into the `sp_executesql` (it runs in a different scope that doesn't have access to variables declared in the calling scope).

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE value > @t'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@t numeric', @t=@tolerance
```

Comment: what this `N` means?

Comment: oh I guess the `N` before `' '` says that in brankets is numeric value not character

Comment: `N` means `NVARCHAR` since `sp_executesql` wants nvarchar parameters

Comment: and how modify this when I wanna inject 2 variables or more?

Comment: oh, it goes like this, then: `exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@var1 decimal(10,2), @var2 decimal(10,2)', 
       @var1= @var1, @var2= @var2`

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you're using *Dynamic SQL* here.. try this:

```
create procedure ##sp_check (

    @tolerance numeric
)

AS

SELECT * FROM a WHERE value > @tolerance

go

exec ##sp_check 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a variable declared outside of a dynamic statement inside it. Thus, the correct syntax would be:

```
CREATE PROC ##sp_check (@tolerance numeric)
AS

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM a' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE value > @dtolerance;';
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dtolerance numeric',@dtolerance = @tolerance;

go

exec ##sp_check 1;
```

I suggest, however, you declare your scale and precision on your `numeric`, it's very bad practice to not do so.